# System memory behavior during huge mysql import

Tags: mysql, memory, import

I am importing a huge (~900GB ) dump in a `mysql 5.5` server;

The system has 48GB of RAM.

Here are my InnoDB settings

```
innodb_read_io_threads          = 16
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16  #To stress the double write buffer
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 48000M
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G #Small log files, more page flush
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 1G
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_file_format              = BARRACUDA
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
```

Here is some `vmstat` output in MBs

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0   6324    290      6    206    3    0  7988 29188 1723 1576  7  1 82 10  0
 1  0   6321    294      5    198    5    0 11436 29152 1935 1762  7  1 83  9  0
 0  1   6318    285      5    202    5    0  9364 23940 1516 1350  8  1 82  9  0
 0  1   6316    289      5    195    3    0  8136 30500 1636 1607  5  1 82 12  0
 0  1   6316    288      5    196    0    0   384  5620  296  342  0  0 82 17  0
 0  2   6315    287      5    197    0    0   992   984  173  232  1  0 69 30  0
 0  2   6315    287      5    197    0    0     0     0   85  149  0  0 67 33  0
 1  0   6314    289      5    192    1    0  3384  9788  699  597  2  0 80 18  0
 0  1   6313    294      4    184    3    0  5360 10872  651  689  4  1 82 14  0
 0  1   6310    289      4    185    4    0 10580 16796 1333 1276  7  1 82 10  0
 0  1   6308    289      4    181    4    0  6272 23212 1233 1208  5  1 83 12  0
 0  2   6307    290      4    178    2    0  4220  9956  696  740  3  0 72 25  0
 0  2   6306    286      4    182    0    0  2712  3656  317  322  1  0 68 31  0
 0  2   6305    283      4    182    1    0  4000 17172 1020 1094  3  1 81 15  0
 1  0   6302    291      4    171    4    0  8712 25940 1479 1430  8  1 79 12  0
```

The imported database should be about ~580G and now I am in about ~320G (the import has been running for a couple of days).

Why is the system swappping so heavily?

Is there something I can do (in the middle of the import) to speed it up?

Why I see processes in the `b`(locked) column of `vmstat`? could the import itself being blocked by something?

I have globally disabled foreign key checks.

```
mysql> show variables like 'fo%';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | OFF   |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (2.63 sec)
```

Comment: How are you importing it ? Just a dump? Paste the command please

Comment: `mysql> use thedatabaseIwanttheimportin` and then `mysql> source /path/to/dump.sql`

Comment: Show processlist,    Show Engine InnoDB status. Please paste them too. Probably grep for locks , writes and reads from the status.

Comment: Setting the InnoDB buffer pool size to 100% of system memory as you have done here is not viable.  Swap thrashing is inevitable with this misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

> The system has 48GB of RAM.
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 48000M
>   Why is the system swappping so heavily?

NO, NO, NO!  48G will lead to swapping and possibly crashing.  Use 36G.

You have asked to fill up RAM with the buffer_pool, leaving no room for the OS, MySQL, other caches, etc.

Was the `.sql` file produced by `mysqldump`?  With what parameters?

Comment: `mysqldump` with no parameters at all